# Display an entry value in another page

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I'm creating a simple xaml page who display an entry and a button, I want to create an event for the button to display the entry value into another page.
Should I use the MVVM or there's another method to do that.

this is the first page:

```
                            <!--  Entry to get machine name  -->
                            <border:SfBorder
                                BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Gray-Bg}"
                                BorderColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference PasswordEntry}, Path=IsFocused, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}"
                                Style="{StaticResource LoginFormBorderlessEntryBorderStyle}">
                                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto">

                                    <control:BorderlessEntry
                                        Margin="15,0"
                                        HeightRequest="40"
                                        Placeholder="Le nom de la machine"
                                        Style="{StaticResource BorderlessEntryStyle}"/>
                                        
                                    </control:BorderlessEntry>

                                
                                </Grid>
                            </border:SfBorder>

                        </StackLayout>




                        <!--  Scanner button  -->
                        <buttons:SfButton
                            Grid.Row="5"
                            Margin="0,16"
                            
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            Style="{StaticResource GradientButtonStyle}"
                            Text="Scanner le code QR" 
                            Clicked="Scan"
                           />

                          

                    </Grid>
 </StackLayout>
```

the "scan" method in the button:

```
 private void Scan(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Scanner());}
```

the scanner page:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label ............ the entry value...... />
   <Label x:Name="scanResultText" FontSize="Large"/>
        <zxing:ZXingScannerView IsScanning="True" OnScanResult="ZXingScannerView_OnScanResult"/>
    
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: there are many different ways to do this.  As written, this is a pretty abstract question.  It would help a lot if you would include more detail (code) about the specific example you're trying to solve

Comment: in that case, just pass the value to the `Scanner` via the constructor

Comment: @Jason how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass a value via the page constructor

```
var value = MyEntryControl.Text;
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Scanner(value))
```

and in the `Scanner`

```
public Scanner(string value)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyLabelControl.Text = value;
}
```

Comment: you are such a nice person!